# Change the window reference in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

We have a *friendly* iframe on a document. The iframe loads jQuery. We would like to be able to create another instance of jQuery (perhaps using `noConflict()`), and set the `window` to be the main document window.

I imagine something like this:

```
<!-- Main document -->   
<div id="foo">42</div>
<iframe src="iframe-which-loads-jquery-and-my-script.html"></iframe>
```

Then, in the iframe code, we need something like this:

```
const $mainJquery = createAJQueryInstanceOfTheMainWindow()
mainJquery("#foo").text() // → "42"
```

How is this possible? How can we set a custom `window` object in jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

```
  function createAJQueryInstanceOfTheMainWindow(elem){

                return window.parent.$;  
            }

            const $mainJquery = createAJQueryInstanceOfTheMainWindow();


            $mainJquery(()=>{

               alert($mainJquery("#foo").text());
            })
```

Put this function inside your iframe and you will have new jQuery instance from parent window.

Comment: Sorry, I am asking how to create a new jQuery instance using a different window object...

Comment: Go through my modified answer.It perfectly serves your purpose.

Comment: Bipin, that assumes that the top document has jQuery. But it does not.

Comment: Then $("#foo",window.parent.document).text() is the only possible solution to set parent document context to a jquery selector inside iframe. Or you modify the jquery library and change var document = window.document;  to var document = window.parent.document; uncompressed jquery v3.4.1 has it on line 50. There is no other sane way of passing parent window context to jquery.jquery is a self invoking anonymous function that has its own window reference exclusive set to current loaded window.Please don't down vote this answer.